# Cheerio find child with class that starts with string

Tags: javascript, cheerio

Currently I have an object which has a lot of children. I can find a particular child using:

```
$(elem).find('.animal-type').text();
```

However, some of the `animal-type` classes have different endings: i.e. `animal-types, animal-type1 or longer ones`.

How can I substitute `find('.animal-type')` to look for elements that have a class which starts with `animal-type`?

Comment: Does Cheerio support the jQuery [startsWith](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector? `$(elem).find('[class^="animal"]')`

Comment: @Scrimothy, it does and that is actually part of the CSS spec

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all html elements that have a class which starts with 'animal', this should work: $(elem).find('[class^="animal"]')